# Can a cisco router be configured as vpn site to site tunnel and AnyConnect vpn so can be reached from any place

Tags: vpn, cisco-anyconnect, cisco-router

I have a cisco router 800 series(head office) already configured as vpn tunnel with another router from same model in another branch(warehouse).

My question is:  Is it possible to configure head office router to accept vpn connection from any place (any connect vpn)? And how if possible ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: AnyConnect works with the Cisco ASA.

Comment: Thanks @Appleoddity for reply , Are there any method so can i connect to this router from any place?